# How do I get the color used by plotly express for each bubble in a scatter map?

Tags: plotly, plotly-python

I draw the scatter map using a color continuous scale, looks great. Now I want to know which color is used for each bubble. I am trying to list the labels in respective colors as a table outside the map.

Actual usage is I am drawing a scatter map for trending stocks. I want to color code the tickers with the exact color used by the scatter map.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In plotly, you can use `fig.data` to get information on the plot drawn. As you mentioned that you have used continuous color scale, the `marker.color` will hold the variables for the column you have used for `color` in the scatter plot. Normalizing this between 0 and 1 and then using `sample_colorscale()` will give you an array with the `rgb()` values for the color of each marker.

In the below example, I have used `jet` colorscale. Do change it to what you are using. Note that not providing one will mean that plotly will pick up `viridis` as the default scale. Hope this is what you are looking for...

```
import plotly.express as px
from plotly.express.colors import sample_colorscale
from sklearn.preprocessing import minmax_scale
df= px.data.iris()
fig = px.scatter(df, x="sepal_length", y="sepal_width", color="petal_length", color_continuous_scale="jet")

for d in fig.data:
    c=sample_colorscale('jet', minmax_scale(d.marker.color))
print(c)
```

**Output (150 entries in this example)**

```
['rgb(0, 20, 144)', 'rgb(0, 20, 144)', 'rgb(0, 15, 141)', ....
```